# ¿Cómo puedo analizar el volumen en un momento especifico de un audio en JS?

Tags: javascript, audio

Quiero saber el volumen o "amplitude" de un audio (MP3, OGG, etc.) en un momento especifico de ese y que el valor del volumen se muestre en la consola, con JavaScript.
Por ejemplo:

Que me muestre cuanta "amplitude" habia en el seg. 3 del audio, o en el seg. 7.65, etc.

Pregunto esto debido a que he buscado utilizando el Web Audio API y me he confundido mucho, espero recibir una respuesta

Comment: Hola, ¿que has investigado/probado hasta el momento? ¿Te has planteado usar una biblioteca? Buscando "amplitude JS audio" en Internet he encontrado la biblioteca [p5.js](https://p5js.org/examples/sound-measuring-amplitude.html) que parece hacer lo que buscas.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro En realidad no me he planteado usar una biblioteca, pensaba mejor hacerlo desde el JavaScript Vanilla (normal), si conozco y uso p5.js, pero en realidad el p5.js sound no lo se usar bien. Asi que, ¿por favor me dices como puedo hacerlo con p5.js?